# Arguments in command line

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

Why do we need a mechanism like  argv and argc  in c programming language?

How is this mechanism implemented?

```
main(argc, argv) int argc; char *argv[];
{ 
   int i;
   for (i=1; i < argc; i++) 
      printf("%s%c", argv[i], (i < argc-1) ? ' ':'\n');
}
```

Comment: You may want o learn a few things about commands in your shells...

Comment: Arguments are useful because they allow information to be passed to the process by the party that starts the process.

Answer (score 1):

First off, modern C would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
  int i;
  for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s%c", argv[i], (i < argc-1) ? ' ':'\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

To answer your question, command line arguments are just another way of giving input to your program (along with the standard input stream and environment variables). It allows you to separate program input (stdin) from program options (commandline flags)

Comment: I think modern C would also do `for (int i=1; ...` instead of `int i; (for i=1; ...`.

Comment: People are still using c89 compilers.  I think Microsoft's C compiler failed to support c99 as of only a few years ago.